# Docker Compose not seeing command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run an exporter [this](https://github.com/cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch) using docker compose. I have created a docker compose file like this :-

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus-cloudwatch:
    image: cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch
    container_name: prometheus-cloudwatch
    command:
      - 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
      - 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'
      - 'CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE=${CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE}'
      - 'CLOUDWATCH_REGION=${CLOUDWATCH_REGION}'
      - 'CLOUDWATCH_PUBLISH_TIMEOUT=15'
      - 'PROMETHEUS_SCRAPE_INTERVAL=30'
      - 'PROMETHEUS_SCRAPE_URL=http://IP:9399/metrics'
```

And i have created .env file with the following content :-

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<ID>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<ID>
CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE=kube-state-metrics
CLOUDWATCH_REGION=us-east-1
```

When i run the command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and check the running containers, using `docker ps -a` i get this :-

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
cf43bfedef54   cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch   "prometheus-to-cloud…"   7 minutes ago   Exited (1) 7 minutes ago             prometheus-cloudwatch
```

And when i further investigate using `docker logs prometheus-cloudwatch`, I am seeing this :-

```
2021/07/28 03:15:44 prometheus-to-cloudwatch: Error: -cloudwatch_namespace or CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE required
```

Which does not make sense to me since i have declared the command in the docker-compose file. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch/blob/master/Dockerfile#L12):

> ENTRYPOINT ["prometheus-to-cloudwatch"]

In fact, The `command` in your `docker-compose.yaml` will be act as parameters of the entrypoint.

To make the same effect of `-e CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE` mentioned [here](https://github.com/cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch#run-in-a-docker-container), you could try next snippet:

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus-cloudwatch:
    image: cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch
    container_name: prometheus-cloudwatch
    env_file: .env
```

You could refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) for more help.

Another solution is using `environment` like next, but you need to extract the variable by yourself, detail see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment):

```
environment:
  - CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE=${CLOUDWATCH_NAMESPACE}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this did the job. appreciate the help.